# script that pre-fills a textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, textfield

I'm trying to find a script that will fill a textfield of say an  optin form with a text like 'fill in your e-mail address' and dissappear when click on. I know they're all over the net but searching for it only returns javascript autofill scripts where suggestions are listed from a dropdown below the textfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use on my website Expiringlinks.co. Now, if you only want to apply this to one input, change $('input') to $('#yourinputid'). The input field should have a value field that equals your before text.

```
var tempValue='';
    $('input').click(function(){
        tempValue = $(this).attr('value');
        $(this).attr('value','');

    });

    $('input').focusout(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('value')==''){
        $(this).attr('value',tempValue);
        }


    });
```

For you input field

```
<input type="text" value="Whatever you want to show before the click" />
```

Comment: @the_visit Did you want it to blank out the textbox every time you click in it? Eg. click in the box, enter something, click out, then click back in - it will blank it again - do you want that, or not? Just checking :)

Comment: @joe - Hasn't even crossed my mind to be honest. I think this is fine. I appreciate you asking me though. Maybe would be a great exercise for my brain :-)

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 supports placeholder text, which you can use like this

```
  <input name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" />
```

This will automatically disappear when you click on the textfield. For older browsers, you can use one of the above suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5GMhS/)

Or, a slightly different [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5GMhS/2/) that doesn't require an ID on the label, but needs the textbox/label to be wrapped in something, for example a `<p>` tag.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="email_address" id="Email" />
<label for="Email" id="EmailLabel">Please enter your email address</label>
```

CSS

```
label
{
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#Email').focus(function()
    {
        $('#EmailLabel').show();
    }).blur(function()
    {
        $('#EmailLabel').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: @the_visit Another option, just for the fun of it :) http://jsfiddle.net/ShtxJ/ OK, I'm done now.

Comment: that's great, definately going to be using that soon when It's even more detail time for my project